# Smooth animation effect

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/HGCaF/6/
I am trying to make my div move more smoother when moving down the page and back up, it's hard to describe but if you take a look at the link you will begin to understand what I mean,
Here is a sample structure of the webpage:

```
<div id="window">
    <div id="title_bar">
        <div id="button">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `'#widnow'` ? Check the spelling.

Comment: not really notice how when it goes up or down the page it goes really fast and doesn't look like it's controlled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing that:

CSS:

```
#window{
    width:400px;
    border:solid 1px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#box").slideToggle();

    if($(this).html() == "-"){

        $(this).html("+");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#window').css('top', 'auto');
            $('#window').animate({ 'bottom': '0' }, 500);
        }, 500);
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#window').animate({ 'top': '0' }, 500);
            $('#window').css('bottom', 'auto');
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Works in FF, I haven't tested other browsers.